# Removing Values in Array using .splice() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm attempting to loop through an array and remove any values that equal false, null, 0, undefined, NaN, or "".

When I call the function it should return a blank array but right now it's outputting `[null,0,null,null,""]`. Here's what I have so far.

```
 function bouncer(arr) {
      for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]===false||null||0||undefined||NaN||""){
          arr.splice(i,1);
        }
      }
    return arr;
    }

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why it is not removing these values from the array?

Comment: You're if condition is wrong, that is not how you check a variable against multiple values. Also you shouldn't iterate over an array while modifying it without taking proper steps (eg iterating backwards)

Comment: Have you considered using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead?

Comment: Also, once you remove one element, all the others are shifted. So if you remove arr[0], the for loop will continue next time with arr[1], but as the array was shifted, that arr[1] is what used to be at arr[2]. So you'll be skipping elements (try in the reverse order to avoid this).

Comment: Also, do you know that `if(!arr[i]) {` will get most of the work done for you?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Could you be a little more specific about what exactly is wrong about my if condition?

Comment: @MondKin didn't know that either but that's an excellent point! Thank you

Comment: @fubar I have considered using .filter and I probably will make an implementation with that function as well. I'm just trying to familiarize myself with the .splice() function more right now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
if(arr[i]===false||null||0||undefined||NaN||""){...}
```

The correct way to compare for multiple values is:

```
if(arr[i]===false|| arr[i]=== null|| arr[i]===  0||arr[i] ===  undefined|| arr[i] ===  NaN|| arr[i]===  ""){ ..}
```

You can simplify it further as all values we need to filter naturally evaluates to false

```
if(!arr[i])
```

Reimplementation of your function with the index adjusted for splicing:

```
function bouncer(arr){
    for( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ){
        if(!arr[i]){
            arr.splice(i--,1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

A better way to do this with immutability is by using `Array.filter`

```
function bouncer(arr){
    return arr.filter((item) => (!!item));
}
```

Comment: @RaphaMex I tried experimenting in my browser console with a few logs.. Looked okay to me.. can you show me a case where that might happen?

Comment: Sorry you're right, `.length` is re-evaluated at each loop. Nothing to edit.

Answer (score 0):

mistakes:

1. Should be `if(arr[i]===false||arr[i]===null||arr[i]===0||arr[i]===undefined||arr[i]===NaN||arr[i]==="")`
2. Since `NaN !== NaN`, should use `isNaN(arr[i])`
3. `if (...) {
      arr.splice(i,1); 
      i--; // should minus one here!
    }`

Comment: 2. Should the condition then be arr[i]===isNaN(nan) ?

Comment: @PaulPearce `isNaN(arr[i])`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the javascript language syntax descriptions, again.

```
if(arr[i]===false||null||0||undefined||NaN||"") ...
```

means, if arr[i] is false, or null is true or 0 is true or undefined is true or NaN is true or "" is true. The first part depends on what arr[i] is, but the rest will all be false. That means we can simplify your statement, as written, to:

```
if (arr[i] === false) ...
```

Since the all the rest will always be false. But inferring what you want to *do*, you might want to say

```
if (arr[i] == false) ...
```

which will perform a looser, less rigorous comparison (i.e., it won't check the types of the elements being compared) and will test what I infer you want.

However, your logic has another problem: you are removing elements *as you're* iterating over the array, `i` is advancing as you are removing elements from under it. Another approach might be to build up the returned array (rather than modify the input array).

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  var r=[];
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if ( arr[i] )
      r.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return r;
}
```

Or better yet, use a method which is designed for the purpose of determining elements to keep (though it does not modify the original array, so you'll have to reassign it:

```
arr = arr.filter(function (elem) { return elem; });
```